# Automatically connect to google drive on app launch

Tags: android, kotlin, google-drive-api, google-client

I am creating an Android app with Kotlin. I need the app to to connect to google drive with an already specified account in the props when the app launches.

I have created an API project on Google Cloud Console, set OAuth consent screen, and created credentials. What to do after that?

Comment: is it a standard drive account you will be accessing?  one you control or are you trying to access the accounts of you users

Comment: An account I control. @LindaLawton-DaImTo

Comment: use a service account